# Cannot convert ‘timeval*’ to ‘PTIMEVAL {aka __ms_timeval*}’

Tags: boost, wxwidgets, filezilla

Getting this error during wxWidgets compilation for [FileZilla](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Compiling_FileZilla_3_under_Windows) on Windows10/MSYS2/Cygwin.

> $ ./configure --prefix="$HOME/prefix" --enable-static --disable-shared
>   --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-unicode --without-libtiff --without-libjpeg --with-expat=builtin --with-libpng=builtin --disable-fsvolume

```
$ make

/home/alex_buz/wx3/bk-deps g++ -c -o netlib_socket.o -I./.pch/wxprec_netlib -D__WXMSW__      -DWXBUILDING    -I./src/png -I./src/zlib -I./src/regex -I./src/expat/lib -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/home/alex_buz/wx3/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-static-3.0 -I./include -DWX_PRECOMP -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing  ./src/common/socket.cpp
./src/common/socket.cpp: In member function ‘wxSocketEventFlags 
wxSocketImpl::Select(wxSocketEventFlags, const timeval*)’:

./src/common/socket.cpp:1343:73: error: cannot convert ‘timeval*’ to ‘PTIMEVAL {aka __ms_timeval*}’ for argument ‘5’ to ‘int select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, PTIMEVAL)’
     const int rc = select(m_fd + 1, preadfds, pwritefds, &exceptfds, &tv);
                                                                         ^
make: *** [Makefile:29796: netlib_socket.o] Error 1
```

Google search gave some hints that it's related to boost. 
Any way to resolve it?

Comment: I don't know why does this happen but I'd recommend against building using Cygwin native compiler in any case, install the native compiler and use `--host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=i686-pc-cygwin` as explained in this [old blog post](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2011/06/choosing-gcc-for-building-wxwidgets.html).

Answer (score 0):

Both values are different structures, because the members are of different **type**. Look at the definition code of them.

You cant convert them => make an instance and set the members.